# After the Update System is still showing the Old OS

Tags: macos

After the Update System is still showing the Old OS check the screenshot

[image: screenshot]

and if i click on the system update there is no os update just some other updates.check the screenshot[image]

please help me out

Answer (score 1):

This happens to me occasionally—after installing the latest update my iMac reboots and it’s still running its previous version. I just run the update again, then everything updates correctly.

Just download and install the latest macOS Sierra Update image from Apple. As of June 6th, 2017, that would be [10.12.5](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1918).